# How to Make an Element Appear and Disappear via Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html

So I have built a website that is to be part of my portfolio going forward. As a joke, I have put "do you want to hire me?" above a yes/no radio button. I am trying to make it so that my CV appears when the user clicks yes. I have tried a few different ways to make this work via JavaScript but no joy. Please help.

```js
function revealCV() {
  document.getElementById("cv").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" onclick="revealCV()" id="yes" name="hire" value="Yes">
  <label for="yes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" id="no" name="hire" value="No">
  <label for="no">No</label>
</form>

<br>

<a
  id="cv"
  style="display:none"
  href="C:\Users\DSGO\Downloads\Tom O'Hanlon CV (2).pdf"
  download="Tom O'Hanlon CV">
    <img src="C:\Users\DSGO\Downloads\Tom O'Hanlon CV (2).pdf" alt="CV">
</a>
```

Comment: that code works to show the CV contrarily to what you stated.  Did you mean how to make it disappear again if you click "No"?

Comment: That's odd, when I run it it doesn't work for me. I just want to make my CV appear when they click yes. I have tried so many different ways and none work.

Comment: Are you saying that if you run the snippet in your question, when you click the "Yes" radio option the link CV doesn't show up?? if that's the case you are having some other issues beyond the question. Are you sure javascript is enabled in your browser? which browser and version are you using? Or maybe did you mean to show the actual CV content? it would be strange because your code just had an hidden anchor element that you just flip to display: block

Comment: I thought I was going mad because it wasn't working. JavaScript is enabled and I'm using Chrome Version 109.0.5414.75

Comment: your scenario is impossible to address. you said it doesn't work for me but at this point I just think you expected to work if it did something totally different from what's supposed to do. You didn't answer my question before. How do you know it's not working? is the link not appearing?

Comment: The links not appearing. I trust you've given me the correct advice so it must be an issue elsewhere so I'll keep searching. Thanks for your help I appreciate it

Comment: ok if you are just not seeing the link it's a serious issue with your browser. Maybe you have addons affecting the correct execution of the page. You may try opening that page in an incognito window